# Unwanted whitespace while embeding videos (Between videos and paragraphs)

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design

I've wanted to embed 3 videos in a row with Headings above them and Paragraphs underneath them, while also keeping it responsive.

I am doing it for the very first time and every tutorial is not working as i want it to.

Also the videos seem to be cut from the bottom.

What's the best reasonable way of creating my idea with html and css?

```html
<div class="headingiP">
   <h4 id="yt01p">CS 50 - 2019 playlist</h4>
   <h4 id="yt02p">
      How To Think Like A Programmer 
   </h4>
   <h4 id="yt03p">10 Years of Coding<br> in 10 Minutes</h4>
</div>
<div id="filmosy">
   <iframe id="yt01"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jjqgP9dpD1k" frameborder="0"
      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   <iframe id="yt02"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/azcrPFhaY9k" frameborder="0"
      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   <iframe id="yt03"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UMKWijxv0kE" frameborder="0" 
      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div id="underfilmy">
   <p id="underfilm1">
      This course will get you through all the basics concepts we mention above, in a very fun and beginner-friendly lectures, conducted by - David J. Malan 
   </p>
   <p id="underfilm2">
      Andy Harris from "Coding Tech" Youtube channel will help you understand how to think like a programmer, he breaks down common assumptions about
      programmer's work and shows simple examples of basic programming concepts. 
   </p>
   <p id="underfilm3">A Computer Science Harvard Student talks about his experience with programming and various projects he had completed throughout his journey of coding.
      It may be helpful for you to understand how programming can be used in everyday life. 
   </p>
</div>
```

```css
.headingiP {
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#yt01p {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 30%;
    padding-top: 3%;
}

#yt02p {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 30%;
    padding-right: 6%;
    padding-top: 3%;
}

#yt03p {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 30%;
    padding-right: 13%;
    padding-top: 3%;
}

#filmosy {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}

#yt01 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 22%;
    padding-left: 4%;
}

#yt02 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 22%;
    padding-left: 5%;
}

#yt03 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 22%;
    padding-left: 5%;
}

#underfilmy {
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#underfilm1 {
    width: 17%;
    display: table-cell;
    height: auto;
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    font-size: 85%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5%;
}

#underfilm2 {
    width: 17%;
    display: table-cell;
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    font-size: 85%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 4%;
}

#underfilm3 {
    width: 17%;
    display: table-cell;
    height: auto;
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    font-size: 85%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 11%;
}
```

That's the main part of the code yet I think you need to check it on codepen to see it in action really.

https://codepen.io/paulshepherd/pen/eYdjxJQ

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are working with oldfashioned tables and absolute percentages. I would suggest a `flexbox`.

See my updated code: https://codepen.io/erdaepfelsalat/pen/LYRBqMR

Comment: You're welcome! I would be happy to receive an upvote ;-)

Comment: I'd love you to upvote you but I don't have enough "reputation" yet.. I'll get back and upvote it when I will be able to tho.

Comment: I've come up with something like this using flexbox, any idea why paragraphs are not centered? @dagrega

https://codepen.io/paulshepherd/pen/MWjBxxj

Comment: nvm got it, instead of setting width to individual paragraphs, you need to set padding-left/right in % targeting paragraphs in a container 

.programming-container p{
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 25%;
  padding-right: 25%;
  
}

like so. ( leaving for people that will have the same problem )